# TWO show/hide toggles (and their hide if click outside div) issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, hide

I would like to include two button toggles to show/hide two different elements and hide those elements when clicked outside of the div area. I have been researching all day long and while I found the answers for working with only one element, I cannot make it work with two. The second element just doesn't show up if I include the code to hide when click outside the div. Here is the code:

```js
function myFunction() {

  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

}

function myOtherFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myResponsive").classList.toggle("show");

}

window.onclick = function(e) {

  if (!(e.target.matches('.dropbtn') || e.target.matches('.mobile-button'))) {

    var myDropdown =
      document.getElementById("myDropdown");

    var myResponsive =
      document.getElementById("myResponsive");

    if ((myDropdown.classList.contains('show')) ||
      (myResponsive.classList.contains('show'))) {

      myDropdown.classList.remove('show');

      myResponsive.classList.remove('show');

    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  float: left
}

.responsive-menu {
  display: none;
  float: left;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">menu1</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
    <a href="">item 1</a>
    <a href="">item 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="mobile-button" id="mobileMenu" onclick="myOtherFunction()">menu2</button>

  <div class="responsive-menu" id="myResponsive">
    <a href="">item1</a><br>
    <a href="">item2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

A little bit of help and advice would be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you're not using the Element.matches method properly. The Element.matches method only takes one argument corresponding to the selector you want to match for ([see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)). You've passed two arguments to it, and it just ignores the second one.

To fix, just modify your if statement as follows to use the Element.matches method correctly:

```
if (!(e.target.matches('.dropbtn') || e.target.matches('.mobile-button')))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it has been very helpful. Funny enough it only worked at first in my post embedded code, not on my actual website. My "menu2" button was originally an image, and for some reason I couldn't make it work until I changed it for text.